# Do animals defy gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, biophysics, biology

I am a beginner and trying to understand the concept of gravity

Do animals defy gravity?

If yes, which animal defies and in what way it does?

Sorry had I asked something wrong

Comment: What makes you think that animals can defy gravity? Is it because birds can fly?

Comment: @Curious   That's one reason.  As I am very new, trying to understand the concept by gaining opinions from blogs

Comment: OK, maybe you want to stay away from "blogs" that talk about animals that can defy gravity. Gravity acts exactly the same on any form of matter, living or dead. If you like eating chicken, you may have noticed that birds have very strong breast muscles. That's because it's mainly the breast muscles that move the wings in a bird. Flying is VERY hard, even for birds, and they have exquisitely well developed muscles for that purpose.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean defy? What doesn't defy gravity and why should it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No animal, object or person defies gravity. Not here on earth, not in any place on the universe.
Ask yourself this question on another form: When a plane, or a bird, flies, is he(it) defying gravity? No! They are just balancing forces, pushing air behind then, so it can compensate their weight. The direction of the resultant vector of forces combined, is up.

Answer (score 1):

It has been found that gravity, understood as force, acts on any body of any shape or material depending only on the mass of the body. In fact, gravity understood as the curvature of spacetime acts on all of matter and energy, including light.

In this way, nothing defies gravity: it is one of the most universal phenomena known to man.

Colloquially, one might use the sentence "defying gravity" to describe behaviour of certain animals or machines that not only do not fall or fly, but that do so in a way that surprises our general intuition. In this cases however, gravity understood as a force or as the curvature of spacetime, is certainly still acting on it.